# Update file in zip floder on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip, aws-sdk

I have a simple text file that I want update file on amazon S3 storage in zip folder is there way to do that without downloading zip folder?

Answer (score 1):

You have to download the entire zip file, update it, and then upload the updated zip file.